# FeathersJs - Sanitize response from Find method in users service broke Authentication service

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-sequelize, feathers-authentication, feathers-hook, feathers-service

I created an after hook in the users service that should sanitize the response from the "find" method and it broke the authentication service.

The after hook **sanitizeResponse** should verify if the query is regarding the email or cpf, and, if it is, should remove some of the fields and add some new ones.

Here is the **users.hooks.js**

```
const { authenticate } = require('@feathersjs/authentication').hooks;

const {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  hashPassword, protect
} = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local').hooks;

const sanitizeResponse = (context) => {
  const query = context.params.query;
  if(!query.email && !query.cpf)
    return context;
  
  if(context.result.total){
    context.result.data[0] = {exists: 1, id: context.result.data[0].id};
  }else{
    context.result.data[0] = {exists: 0};
  }
};

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [authenticate('jwt')],
    get: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    create: [ hashPassword('password') ],
    update: [ hashPassword('password'),  authenticate('jwt') ],
    patch: [ hashPassword('password'),  authenticate('jwt') ],
    remove: [ authenticate('jwt') ]
  },

  after: {
    all: [ 
      // Make sure the password field is never sent to the client
      // Always must be the last hook
      protect('password')
    ],
    find: [sanitizeResponse],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  }
};
```

Before writing this hook the authentication used to work just fine, but afterwards it started sending me "Not authenticated" responses.

I haven not changed anything in the user.class.js and authentication.js file generated by feathersjs-cli.

I would like to know what am i doing wrong ? Is there a better way to sanitize the response ?

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication flow needs to be able to retrieve the full user information to add it to requests, compare passwords and more. You likely want to skip the `sanitizeResponse` [hook for internal calls](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#params) (when `context.params.provider` is `undefined`):

```
const sanitizeResponse = (context) => {
  const query = context.params.query;
  if(!context.params.provider || (!query.email && !query.cpf))
    return context;
  
  if(context.result.total){
    context.result.data[0] = {exists: 1, id: context.result.data[0].id};
  }else{
    context.result.data[0] = {exists: 0};
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, your explanation was really helpful !